# Fold cards and expand a bit on hover

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to create a stack of cards that can be any number of cards.

When Im hovering they should fold out just a bit. This work but only to some degree.
When the screen size is perfect everything looks nice, but then as seen in my example below the last cards starts to place them self away from the pile of cards.

This is most likely do to my lack of experince with grid.

Could someone please help me in the right direction,
or maybe there is a better solution not using grid?

**This do not apply anymore:** *Change the yellow-box width and side-scroll inside the green-box to see the affect on the card pile.*

I have updated this post with a working solution basted on @Paul solution.

```css
/*.wrapper-yellow {
  min-width: 30px;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
  max-width: fit-content;
  padding:20px;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
   border-radius: 8px;
   
}*/

.wrapper-list {
     /* 
     Old Solution commented out, new code based on Pauls anwser
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(17px, 1fr));
     grid-gap: 0%;*/
     
    display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
    
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
   
    padding:10px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    border-radius: 8px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    scrollbar-width: none;
}

.wrapper-list:hover > div:not(:first-child) {
      cursor: pointer;
     /* grid-gap: 1%;*/
       margin-left: -125px;
}

  
.wrapper-list::-webkit-scrollbar {
          display: none;
}

.card {
    position: relative;
    height: 114px;
    width: 164px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    background-color: red;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    border-radius: 8px;
    
    display: inline-block;
    flex-shrink: 0;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

/*.wrapper-list div:nth-child(n) {
      grid-row: 1 / 1;
}*/

.wrapper-list div:not(:first-child) {
      margin-left: -150px;
}
```

```html
<!-- <div class="wrapper-yellow"> -->
  <div class="wrapper-list">
    <div class="card" style="z-index:25"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:24"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:23"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:22"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:21"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:20"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:19"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:18"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:17"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:16"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:15"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:14"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:13"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:12"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:11"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:10"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:9"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:8"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:7"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:6"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:5"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:4"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:3"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:2"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:1"></div>
 </div>
<!-- </div>-->
```

Comment: You're assigning a z-index to every card in the list. Surely this could be implied simply through the position in the parent object. Also, why not just refer to `.wrapper div` (i.e. the child of the wrapper class), rather than assigning a class to every `div`?

Comment: z-index is to get the affect of the pile go from left to right, I could not get it to work any other way. The div-child thing, I did it this way just to higlight my problem on SO, the structure of the html is not my issue  :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I got something similar to work using this code...

```html
<div class="desktop">

    <div class="deck">
    
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est eos quam modi cumque placeat earum veritatis saepe itaque. Inventore aliquid quaerat numquam quasi, velit corrupti quam ad dolorum amet consectetur!</div>
        <div>Numquam pariatur laboriosam harum possimus dignissimos vero officiis officia, nisi excepturi mollitia magnam, quaerat maxime tenetur blanditiis sunt minus magni cupiditate consequatur unde reiciendis recusandae aspernatur esse deleniti ducimus! Nisi?</div>
        <div>Nam voluptas dolorum, alias expedita ea beatae! Non doloremque in blanditiis animi voluptatum itaque unde laboriosam quos veritatis nobis, ex quam odio est quibusdam voluptas modi, sit vitae. Nam, maiores.</div>
        <div>Dolorum, impedit nostrum doloremque dolorem ipsum saepe eos ut voluptates repudiandae vero omnis minima ex. Quasi temporibus excepturi praesentium in blanditiis ex laboriosam est odio suscipit ratione, necessitatibus esse enim.</div>
        <div>Nobis adipisci autem distinctio vero voluptas soluta aspernatur sequi non, illo, architecto ab modi accusamus? Soluta voluptatibus pariatur provident ad ratione corrupti minus! Mollitia doloremque voluptates doloribus sit dignissimos quibusdam?</div>
        <div>Placeat alias iste nobis, tempora sequi at dignissimos exercitationem facilis minus vel ducimus pariatur inventore? Consequuntur dolor, cumque, quis fugit nihil voluptates labore eligendi nobis enim, inventore fuga ducimus culpa.</div>
        <div>Incidunt rerum fuga vel at officiis maiores distinctio, dolore ex iusto quidem dolorem aut id quod, facere laudantium vero, blanditiis minima nostrum exercitationem quisquam recusandae! Nihil aliquid esse quisquam nesciunt.</div>
        <div>Mollitia labore, aut tenetur fuga ut deleniti excepturi maiores eum blanditiis explicabo, recusandae deserunt eius optio et voluptatum reiciendis sapiente repudiandae. Accusamus quibusdam, voluptas rem iste quis ab vitae. Reprehenderit.</div>
        <div>Possimus eaque sed in enim omnis sapiente id autem, numquam, a ab neque dolores commodi, pariatur quos nihil suscipit! Quibusdam doloremque quo eaque deserunt incidunt suscipit accusantium magni vero laborum.</div>
        <div>Hic nostrum distinctio aut iure! Aliquid minima explicabo est adipisci laudantium dignissimos consequatur deleniti doloremque ut, maxime minus tempora laborum corrupti, nostrum deserunt vitae voluptatem nam perspiciatis earum. Doloremque, sequi!</div>
    
    </div>

</div>
```

...with this CSS...

```css
* {font-family: arial; font-size: 18px;}
.desktop {background-color: #052; padding: 20px; text-align: center;}
.deck div {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: -10px 0px 20px #333;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.deck div :first-child {margin-left: 0; }

.deck div:hover {left: -40px;}
```

No repeated z-index or references to a card class.

It's a little messy, to be fair, but kind of achieves what you want. There's probably a hundred bettwer ways to achieve this, though, but I'm not really a CSS expert.

**EDIT**

Just to add to this, to reverse the appearance of the deck, simply change the numbers for the `hover` and `margin-left`, like so...

```css
.deck div {
    ...
    margin-left: -230px;
}

.deck div:hover {left: 30px;}
```

Comment: Thx man, this helped med solve the issue! need to keep the z-zindex in my case.
Will update my post with the changes.

Comment: You're welcome. Have an excellent New Year. :o)

Comment: Instead of using a z-index, try changing the margin-left - that way, the same thing still happens, except the direction of the stack changes.

Comment: I did try without z-index but the stacking looked wrong no mather what, but will fiddle with it more for sure. I have updated my post now with working solution based on your code and thx U have a great New Year to! <3

Comment: @J4v4Scr1pt - I've updated my answer to show you how to change this one easily. PS: if you include a top of, say, -30px, the card appears to pop-up, too (e.g. `.deck div:hover {left: 30px; top: -30px;}`

Comment: Sorry missed your comment. Ok thx will try that! :)

Answer (score 1):

I did some changes to your `css`, Please check if that is what you expect.

```css
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(17px, 1fr));
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    grid-gap: 0px;
    width:100%;
    border: 2px solid green;
    border-radius: 8px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    scrollbar-width: none;
}

.wrapper:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
      grid-gap: 1%;
}
  
.wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
          display: none;
}

.card {
    position: relative;
    height: 114px;
    width: 164px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    background-color: red;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(n) {
      grid-row: 1 / 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="card" style="z-index:25"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:24"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:23"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:22"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:21"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:20"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:19"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:18"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:17"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:16"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:15"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:14"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:13"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:12"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:11"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:10"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:9"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:8"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:7"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:6"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:5"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:4"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:3"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:2"></div>
    <div class="card" style="z-index:1"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thx, but sorry. The changes fixes only this specific width of the post-width. If you add more cards 30+ they will start to place them self wrong again.  :/

Comment: I see, I think you should use more percentages instead of fixed values for the widths.

Comment: I updated my post with rezise abillity to better show the issue